# Flask: Using multiple packages in one app

Tags: python, routes, blogs, package, flask

I'm just getting started with flask and I've hit a snag. I'm trying to write a small blog to get used to the framework so I made two packages, an "auth" and "posts". I read through the Large Applications section in the [Flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/).

My directory looks like this.

```
>/root
>>run.py 

>>/posts

>>>____init____.py  
>>>views.py  
>>>/templates
>>>/static  

>>/auth  
>>>____init____.py  
>>>views.py  
>>>/templates
>>>/static
```

the run.py looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from auth import auth_app
from posts import posts_app

auth_app.run()
posts_app.run()
```

`/posts/__init__.py` and `/auth/__init__.py` look like this:

```
from flask import Flask

auth_app = Flask(__name__)

import auth.views
```

and the views.py look like this:

```
from auth import auth_app

@auth_app.route('/auth/')
def index():
    return "hello auth!"
```

But whenever I run the server, only the localhost/auth/ is available, and everything else gives a 404, som I'm assuming that the posts app isnt being run.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your auth_app.run() method blocks your program from continuing to run. This is why the the posts_apps app doesn't get run. The entire process of serving up pages happens within Flask's run() method. Therefore, you can conclude that you can't run two Flask apps in the same process.

If you wish to split up your application into two like this, the recommended way is to use [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/#blueprints). Rather than creating two apps (auth and posts), you create two blueprints. You then create one application like so...

```
from flask import Flask
from auth import auth_blueprint
from posts import post_blueprint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
app.register_blueprint(post_blueprint)
app.run()
```

Comment: What if the `auth` and `post` blueprints had to use a `models.py` module defined at the root level, along with `run.py`? Then would it make sense to declare them as blueprints, even if they weren't "completely independent" from the main application and thus not reusable in other applications that don't have the same `models.py`? Thank you!

Comment: @miguel5 What you define as "independent" is up to you. The Flask blueprints help provide a way to separate the things that base Flask cares about: the location of the static and template files, the URLs and how they map to your views, etc. If you only want to use this to keep these directories different, but still rely on a single `model.py`, then that is fine. If you wish to also separate your models into the various data structures, you can do that as well. Flask itself does not care how you store your `models.py` file.

Answer (score 6):

Though it seems as though Mark's approach using blueprints fits your project well, if you want to use separate applications for each package you should look into [`werkzeug.wsgi.DispatcherMiddleware`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appdispatch/).

A single process cannot run a second app after you run the first (like in your question), but that's not a problem with DispatcherMiddleware. You can use it to define a main application as well as others based on URL prefixes.

The example on the docs distinguishes between two applications --frontend and backend-- which are run depending on the URL the user requests.

If you want to learn more, read Matt Wright's ["How I Structure My Flask Applications"](http://mattupstate.com/blog/how-i-structure-my-flask-applications/) and look at [Overholt](https://github.com/mattupstate/overholt/blob/master/wsgi.py), his sample project. He decides to use two apps: one for the main website (the frontend) and another for the API, and he creates the distinction between the two based on the URL prefix. From his code*:

```
    from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
    from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
    from overholt import api, frontend


    application = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend.create_app(), {
        '/api': api.create_app()
    })


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        run_simple('0.0.0.0', 5000, application, use_reloader=True, use_debugger=True)
```

This way, he creates two applications wherein each has its defined set of views, configurations, etc. and is able to run them from the same Python interpreter process.

*Note that `run_simple()` is only meant to be used for development --not production.